# Installation Pymol error

Tags: linux, installation, pymol

I am trying to install pymol on Centos 6.5. After running setup.sh it looks everything is fine. But when I launch pymol I obtain this error:

/opt/pymol/pymol.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any help,please?
I am quite new in linux as you may notice...

Comment: Did you try with the instructions [here](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install)?

Answer (score 0):

Follow te instrucctions [here](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install) and also check that you have installed libGLU, on Ubuntu this library is called libglu1-mesa.